# How to view content of HTML-CSS on an Empty ASP.NET Core Web application

Tags: html, asp.net-core-2.0

I just started getting aquinted with ASP.NET Core and over all with web development (HTML and CSS).

I created new ASP.NET Core Web Application with the empty template and added two simple HTML files - Index.html and Menu.html. When I run the debugging I can't see anything other than the default "Hello World".

Do I miss anything in the process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `Html-Css`, they are static files, you need to enable StaticFile Middleware by `app.UseStaticFiles();`.

Try steps below:

- Modify `Startup.cs` to add `app.UseStaticFiles();`

  ```
  public class Startup
  {
  // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
  // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
  {
  }

  // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
  public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
  {
      if (env.IsDevelopment())
      {
          app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
      }
      app.UseStaticFiles();
      app.Run(async (context) =>
      {
          await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
      });
  }
  }
  ```
- Launch the project and access your static file by entering `https://localhost:44387/index.html`

In addition, you may get familiar with asp.net core from [Introduction to ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

Comment: Fantastisc! It works and I got wiser with ASP.NET Core.